# How do I parse the following time in Golang?

Tags: go

What does the layout for parse look like for this timestamp `2021-10-07 12:44:22 +0530`? I've tried all combinations and still can't seem to get it right! Thanks for all your help!

Btw, this format is generated by a Ruby client (speaking to the Go HTTP Server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the format string `"2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700"` to [parse the time](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Parse) in the question:

```
t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700", "2021-10-07 12:44:22 +0530")
```

[Run an example on Go's playground](https://go.dev/play/p/kNZltzTFQnp).

Comment: Thank you! Your layout string worked! I used my incoming string as is, which contained a + which didn't work, looks like the Parse func is hardcoded to look for a -0700